# Meteor your application is crashing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm having an issue, I've installed a fresh copy of Meteor on my Windows 7-64 bit, after which I did the following commands:

```
mkdir meteor
cd meteor
meteor create leaderboard
cd leaderboard
```

I do get a folder with generated things for the server & client, however if I do

```
meteor run
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard>meteor run
[[[[[ C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20170119-11:54:04.143(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.meteor\loc
al\build\programs\server\boot.js:348
W20170119-11:54:04.363(2)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20170119-11:54:04.363(2)? (STDERR)    ^
W20170119-11:54:04.363(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:04.364(2)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could n
ot be found in your node_modules
W20170119-11:54:04.365(2)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command
to install it:
W20170119-11:54:04.367(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:04.368(2)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20170119-11:54:04.369(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:04.370(2)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.bab
el-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
W20170119-11:54:04.371(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtim
e.js:181:9)
W20170119-11:54:04.372(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:
106:16)
W20170119-11:54:04.374(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
W20170119-11:54:04.375(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
W20170119-11:54:04.378(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
W20170119-11:54:04.379(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170119-11:54:04.381(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\A
lex\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_
bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20170119-11:54:04.383(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20170119-11:54:04.384(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
=> Exited with code: 1
W20170119-11:54:06.201(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.meteor\loc
al\build\programs\server\boot.js:348
W20170119-11:54:06.203(2)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20170119-11:54:06.203(2)? (STDERR)    ^
W20170119-11:54:06.204(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:06.205(2)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could n
ot be found in your node_modules
W20170119-11:54:06.206(2)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command
to install it:
W20170119-11:54:06.208(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:06.209(2)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20170119-11:54:06.211(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:06.211(2)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.bab
el-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
W20170119-11:54:06.213(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtim
e.js:181:9)
W20170119-11:54:06.214(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:
106:16)
W20170119-11:54:06.216(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
W20170119-11:54:06.217(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
W20170119-11:54:06.218(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
W20170119-11:54:06.219(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170119-11:54:06.220(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\A
lex\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_
bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20170119-11:54:06.221(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20170119-11:54:06.223(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
=> Exited with code: 1
W20170119-11:54:08.174(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.meteor\loc
al\build\programs\server\boot.js:348
W20170119-11:54:08.175(2)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20170119-11:54:08.176(2)? (STDERR)    ^
W20170119-11:54:08.177(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:08.177(2)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could n
ot be found in your node_modules
W20170119-11:54:08.178(2)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command
to install it:
W20170119-11:54:08.179(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:08.181(2)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20170119-11:54:08.182(2)? (STDERR)
W20170119-11:54:08.183(2)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.bab
el-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
W20170119-11:54:08.184(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtim
e.js:181:9)
W20170119-11:54:08.185(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:
106:16)
W20170119-11:54:08.186(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
W20170119-11:54:08.187(2)? (STDERR)     at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
W20170119-11:54:08.188(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
W20170119-11:54:08.189(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170119-11:54:08.191(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\A
lex\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_
bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20170119-11:54:08.192(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20170119-11:54:08.193(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Alex\Meteor\leaderboard\.met
eor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Like I said this is freshly installed..

Comment: So what happens when you run the command suggested in the error message?

Comment: try to run the project in another port   
meteor run --port 3030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `package.json` file you'll see:

`"dependencies": {
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.18.0"
  }`

You may have missed the instruction in the terminal after the creation of the leaderboard app that said to run `meteor npm install` - run that before `meteor run` and the dependencies will be installed and you can start the leaderboard app.

https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html

Answer (score 1):

Try typing this in your cmd:

```
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

as it is suggested in your error.

If it returned something like:

> Fatal error : git is not installed or not in the PATH

just go ahead and download GIT from [git.com](https://git-scm.com/downloads) then restart your cmd and run your commands ... should be fine as it has worked for me